# Property type 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting the following error message

```
[ts] Property type 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'.

any
```

*This is the TypeScript (JavaScript) that I using*

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
      var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
      ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { });
      ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { });
      ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert( event.url ) });//Property type 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    }
```

*Here are my imports*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { Event } from '@angular/router';
```

Please help!

Comment: `congole.log` your `event` object or use a debugger to check out what it contains. Obviously it doesn't have the url property that you are trying to use in the alert

Comment: If you are sure that your `event` object has `url` field you can declare it as `any` maybe. `function(event: any) { alert( event.url ) }`

Comment: @echonax Thank you it works!

Comment: you should use [platform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/) to check for ready. `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{...})`

Comment: I would not use `any` unnecessarily. That defeats the whole purpose of using TypeScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your event is actually of type `InAppBrowserEvent`, so import it and annotate the parameter with it:

```
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserEvent } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
...
...
function onDeviceReady() {
  var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
  ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { });
  ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { });
  ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event: InAppBrowserEvent) { alert( event.url ) }); //InAppBrowserEvent has 'url' property
}
```